# How to get result in Activity Result of Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i am using following piece of code to send SMS and little modification in email. This code working fine to call activity, but when i use activity For Result it doesn't give any result in activity For Result method. 
Please tell me is there any method to get result when user send sms or cancel the sms.
Thanks in advance.

Code For SMS

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:+923338010570"));
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
             intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

code for Email

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("plain/text");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, EmailList);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
            this.startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

overide onActivityForResult method.

Comment: i know there is a method onActivityForResult, i override this method,
but i got request code, that i sent (100), result code (0) and intent data= null.
Please tell me how in this method i will identify that user has sent the SMS or Cancel the SMS.

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

Comment: Is there no any other way without using this SMS Manager to make my own SMS sending layouts and other stuff ?

Comment: try this http://www.technotalkative.com/android-sending-sms-from-android-application/link here they are using there own layout for sending sms